# SharePoint 2010 - Performance (New-SPWeb $Url).ApplyWebTemplate("{GUID}#MyCustomTemplate")

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

I want to create new SPWebs with a Custom Template.

```
$web = New-SPWeb $Url
$web.ApplyWebTemplate("{GUID}#MyCustomTemplate")
```

My problem is now that the creation from one SPWeb with the Custom Template takes about 40 s on my VM. Is there a other and faster way to create SPWebs with a Custom Template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use -template parameter. For example,

```
New-SPWeb -url $url -template "{GUID}#MyCustomTemplate"
```

I did not have a custom template to use but this took 2 seconds on my system.

Comment: Because I´m using a custom template and and the -template parameter doesn´t work with it. When I´m using "New-SPWeb $Url -template "TemplateName"" it fired a exception because the template is not found.

Answer (score 1):

@LaPhi, you'll get an exception when your custom WebTemplate is not yet activated on your Site (Collection).

I, too, cannot get "New-SPWeb $Url -template "TemplateName" to provision with the Template. You'll likely need to wait until the site is provisioned.

Answer (score 1):

My Solution:
First create the new Web:

```
$web = New-SPWeb $UrlFull
```

After this, apply the Web template

```
$web.ApplyWebTemplate("{GUID}#NameCustomTemplate")
```

The reason is, that the Custom Template is not global.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this syntax

```
New-SPWeb -url $url -template "MyCustomTemplateName#0"
```

You can find these values in Configuration tag of your webtemp_*.xml

```
<Configuration ID="0" Title="MyCustomTemplateName" ...
```